# How to cast a shadow with a gltf model in three.js?

Tags: three.js, gltf

Hey there i'm new to three js & was wondering how to cast a shadow with a gltf model? 
I can see it's possible as it's working [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_gltf_extensions)
I assume i'm not structuring my code correctly-

```
var model = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
model.load('https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/Duck/glTF/Duck.gltf', function(gltf) {scene.add(gltf.scene);});
model.castShadow = true;
```

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/steveham/ckpfwy24/87/

Cheers!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to set `castShadow = true` on each child mesh, like so:

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/Duck/glTF/Duck.gltf', function( gltf ) {

    gltf.scene.traverse( function( node ) {

        if ( node.isMesh ) { node.castShadow = true; }

    } );

    scene.add( gltf.scene );

} );
```

three.js r.113

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot!! here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/steveham/yz7usqeh/33/) for anyone who's interested

Comment: replace `instanceof` with `node.isMesh` if the above doesn't work for you

Comment: @Jorre Updated. Thanks!

Comment: I also had to set `node.receiveShadow = true`.

Comment: This is great, but I had to replace `if ( node.isMesh )` with `if ( node.type === 'Mesh' ) `. I'm using the NPM version 0.137.5

Answer (score -1):

```
            var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.load( 'file path/gltf.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

                gltf.scene.traverse( function ( node ) {

                    if ( node.isMesh || node.isLight ) node.castShadow = true;
                    if ( node.isMesh || node.isLight ) node.receiveShadow = true;

                } );

                gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child.isMesh ) {

                        child.material.envMap = envMap; //reflection of the world

                    }

                } );

                    scene.add( gltf.scene );
```