# why is three.js cast shadow not working on a 3D model

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, mapbox-gl-js, gltf

I have 3D models as such:

[image: model]

I want to add a cast shadow similar to this:

[image: shadow]

And I have the following piece of code responsible for the model:

```js
var ambLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 );
this.scene.add(ambLight)

var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load(path,function (gltf) {
 gltf.scene.traverse( function( model ) {
  if (model.isMesh){ 
   model.castShadow = true; 
  }
 });
 this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
}
```

I added the `castSHadow` part as seen in this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869345/how-to-cast-a-shadow-with-a-gltf-model-in-three-js).

I've tried `model.castShadow = true` and I've tried removing the `if` condition and just leave the `castShadow` but that doesn't work either. Am I missing a step? The full custom layer code is [here](https://codepen.io/TiagoRibeiro94/pen/XWjPXzE?editors=0010) if it helps.

Comment: For one, you need to also set `.receiveShadow = true` for the ground, etc. I played around with shadows once and it's more complex than I thought :) There's probably not a quick and simple answer to this question; I'd also advise you to do more research first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your code, you're trying to add a shadow on top of Mapbox.

For that, apart from the suggestions from @Mugen87, you'll need to create a surface to receive the shadow, and place it exactly below the model you're loading, considering also the size of the object you're loading to avoid the shadow goes out of the plane surface... and then you'll get this.

[image]

Relevant code in [this fiddle I have created](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/jwa9uc1L/2/). I slightly changed the light and I added a light helper for clarity.

```js
var customLayer = {
  id: '3d-model',
  type: 'custom',
  renderingMode: '3d',
  onAdd: function(map, gl) {
    this.camera = new THREE.Camera();
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    dirLight.position.set(0, 70, 100);
    let d = 1000;
    let r = 2;
    let mapSize = 8192;
    dirLight.castShadow = true;
    dirLight.shadow.radius = r;
    dirLight.shadow.mapSize.width = mapSize;
    dirLight.shadow.mapSize.height = mapSize;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.top = dirLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.bottom = dirLight.shadow.camera.left = -d;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.far = 400000000;
    //dirLight.shadow.camera.visible = true;

    this.scene.add(dirLight);
    this.scene.add(new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(dirLight, 10));


    // use the three.js GLTF loader to add the 3D model to the three.js scene
    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(
      'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf',
      function(gltf) {
        gltf.scene.traverse(function(model) {
          if (model.isMesh) {
            model.castShadow = true;
          }
        });
        this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
        // we add the shadow plane automatically 
        const s = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(gltf.scene).getSize(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        const sizes = [s.x, s.y, s.z];
        const planeSize = Math.max(...sizes) * 10;
        const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
        const planeMat = new THREE.ShadowMaterial();
        planeMat.opacity = 0.5;
        let plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
        plane.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
        plane.receiveShadow = true;
        this.scene.add(plane);
      }.bind(this)
    );
    this.map = map;

    // use the Mapbox GL JS map canvas for three.js
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: map.getCanvas(),
      context: gl,
      antialias: true
    });

    this.renderer.autoClear = false;
    this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

  },
  render: function(gl, matrix) {
    var rotationX = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
      new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
      modelTransform.rotateX
    );
    var rotationY = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0),
      modelTransform.rotateY
    );
    var rotationZ = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis(
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
      modelTransform.rotateZ
    );

    var m = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(matrix);
    var l = new THREE.Matrix4()
      .makeTranslation(
        modelTransform.translateX,
        modelTransform.translateY,
        modelTransform.translateZ
      )
      .scale(
        new THREE.Vector3(
          modelTransform.scale,
          -modelTransform.scale,
          modelTransform.scale
        )
      )
      .multiply(rotationX)
      .multiply(rotationY)
      .multiply(rotationZ);

    this.camera.projectionMatrix = m.multiply(l);
    this.renderer.state.reset();
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

    this.map.triggerRepaint();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

- You only have an instance of `AmbientLight` in your scene which is no shadow-casting light.
- 3D objects can only receive shadow if they set `Object3D.receiveShadow` to `true` and if the material is not unlit. Meaning `MeshBasicMaterial` would not work as the ground's material.
- You have to globally enable shadows via: `renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;`

I suggest you have a closer look to the shadow setup of this [official example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_blending).

Comment: I've updated the code , check here: 
https://codepen.io/TiagoRibeiro94/pen/XWjPXzE?editors=0010

Yet, it doesn't work /: I've added the shadowMap.enabled as suggested, switched ambientLight to a directional one. I've very new to js in particular, but even more to three.js, so I'm at a lost atm. Any clue what the issue could be?

Comment: Depending on your scene, the settings for the shadow camera's frustum are not yet correct. I suggest you visually debug the frustum by add this line of code to your app: `scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( dirLight.shadow.camera ) );`. Then ensure that you scene lies within the visualized box.